# Questions about adverb phrases (or prepositional phrase working as complements)

Tags: grammaticality, adverb-position, complements

When there are two adverb phrases of same kind, it is recommended to put the more descriptive one in the front.

But this people used and in between those adverb phrases.

> My room was in the ship and on the 5th floor.

To me, this and seemed redundant to me. Since "in the ship" and "on the 5th floor" are adverb phrases (or are those complements) that modify "was", a to be verb, I thought it better to omit the word and.

> My room was in the ship on the 5th floor.

But it sounds a little unatural. Is my sentence grammatically wrong? And if yes, why is that?

Comment: Since you offer judgements of naturalness, I assume you are a native speaker. As you say, they can be treated like any other adverbs, and don't need the _and_. However, that just means that both structures are available, so that one might be used to emphasize some contextual detail (like the fact, known to the speaker and addressees, that one has to go down five flights to get onto the boat in the first place, thus making the fifth-floor cabin ironic -- there the _and_ would be good, and could even be stressed for contrast.)

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, I'm not a native speker, and that was the reason sentence 2 with no "and" sounded unatural to me, because of the order of adverb phrases. I prefer "on the 5th floor in the ship",  but I thouht that in this case "in the ship" became an adjective phrase... Does keeping this sentence as it is,"in the ship on the fifth floor", sound perfectly  natural to you?

Comment: For some reason,  the second adverb phrase always seems like adjective phrase to me...

Comment: @Columbus If you want John to read your comments you'll need to put an @ sign before his name somewhere in the comment. Most people do it at the beginning. If you don't do that he won't get *pinged* and won't see your message. You can always copy and paste your messages into new comment boxes and insert the addressee into the beginning :)

Comment: If _in the ship_ modifies _fifth floor_, then it's an adjective phrase (really, a reduced relative clause). But if _in the ship_ is a predicate phrase like _on the fifth floor_, then it doesn't really matter what order they appear in. One thing about this is a little odd -- the choice of _floor_ instead of _deck_, which is what they're usually called on shipboard. That gave me pause, and I wondered whether it was by a non-native speaker.

Comment: How do you define 'redundant'? 'Pass salt!' conveys the intended message clearly enough; 'Pass the salt!' is more idiomatic. But 'Would you please pass the salt.' is less likely to alienate people.

Answer (score 1):

These are both preposition phrases functioning as Locative Complements of the verb *BE*. Generally speaking you can add as many Locative Complements as you wish without using any co-ordintors such as *and*. You could always use *and* for emphasis if required, but without any special reason to do so, it's best omitted.

I agree that in the Original Poster's example, *in the ship on the 5th floor* is better, but this is an issue of style not grammar.

Comment: Thank you so much! I can add as many prepositional adverb phrases as I want, right?

Comment: @Columbus Yes!   - if you believe in adverb phrases that don't have adverbs in ;-)

Comment: @Columbus Some people do believe in them, but not me ... :)